# Does Sendgrid provide a response for each email?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid for mass-mailing. I use multiple categories for different emails, after sending the email I want to get all the responses of the email which is sent at Sendgrid side through the API used for sending the mail.

I am getting response  of opening the email but exactly which email is opened that I'm not getting. I want to keep track of each email; is there any need to create common parameters on our server side?

Comment: By "get all the responses of the email", do you mean SMTP server responses? Message are likely to be added to a queue, so if Sendgrid do offer this (and I expect they would) you'll not get the results synchronously - you'll need to make another API call to check how many times they've tried and what responses they got each time.

Answer (score 0):

To view stats on individual emails, you can use the [Email Activity](http://sendgrid.com/logs/index) page, but that only gives you a week's worth of data due to log rotation. There is currently no pull API for this data.

To gather this data programmatically and store it, SendGrid provides an [Event Webhook](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) that will push events to a URL you define in near real-time.

If you still want to associate custom parameters with individual emails, that can be done using [Unique Arguments](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do this by using `unigue_args` parameter. A built-in option would be to use `category` parameter. You can then add this tag when sending out the email via server side.

```
<php? $hdr->setCategory('Bounce Notice'); ?>
```

This would be the returned format.

```
{
  "category": "Example Category"
}
```

I have been building [a repo][2] with a working example of the event notification API which stores information into a local databae. This process will log any of the following: delivered, bounced, delayed, clicked, etc. SendGrid will post events to a script of your choosing via the Apps section in your account.

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/htmlgraphic/SendGrid-Event-Notifications) of Sendgrid Event Notifications